# Network calls in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am making a news app in which I have 3 tabs which are trending, latest and popular. I have implemented the tab layout. Now I have to show list in each fragment when it is selected. I am using google news API below

https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top

now I want to filter data from API based on the tab selected like if tab popular is selected then the URL should be https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=popular, and it will show in the respective fragment.

I have made a network call in the first tab and its working fine for it. But when I switch tabs it's crashing. SO I am confused how can I make network calls based on the tab selected.

Here is my mainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeViews();


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TopStories(), "top stories");
        adapter.addFragment(new Trending(), "trending");
        adapter.addFragment(new Latest(), "latest");
        adapter.addFragment(new Popular(), "popular");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    }


     class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

         private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
         private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

         public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
             super(manager);
         }

         @Override
         public Fragment getItem(int position) {
             return mFragmentList.get(position);
         }

         @Override
         public int getCount() {
             return mFragmentList.size();
         }

         public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
             mFragmentList.add(fragment);
             mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
         }

         @Override
         public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
             return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
         }
     }
```

Fragment1:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_stories,container,false);
        if (ParamConstants.API_KEY.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please obtain your API KEY first from themoviedb.org", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.news_recycle);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        fetchNews(recyclerView);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void fetchNews(final RecyclerView rv) {
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<JsonElement> call = apiService.getNews("google-news", "top", ParamConstants.API_KEY);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                Log.d("resonse", response.toString());
                JsonElement object = response.body();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<News>>() {
                }.getType();
                news = new Gson().fromJson(object.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("articles"), listType);
                rv.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(news, R.layout.news_list_item, getContext()));
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });


        Call<JsonElement> source = apiService.getSources("", "", "");
        source.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                Log.d("sources", response.body().toString());

                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<NewsResponse>>() {
                }.getType();
                newsResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("sources"), listType);
                newsResponse.get(0).getCategory().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("sourcesfailure", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Fragment2:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trending_fragment,container,false);


        if (ParamConstants.API_KEY.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please obtain your API KEY first from themoviedb.org", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.news_recycle);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        fetchTrendingNews(recyclerView);

return rootView;

    }

    private void fetchTrendingNews(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<JsonElement> call = apiService.getNews("BBC News", "popular", ParamConstants.API_KEY);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                Log.d("resonse", response.toString());
                JsonElement object = response.body();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<News>>() {
                }.getType();
                news = new Gson().fromJson(object.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("articles"), listType);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(news, R.layout.news_list_item, getContext()));
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Error Logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.kotlin.whatshappening.activity.fragment.Trending.onCreateView(Trending.java:65)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1464)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.
```

So how I can make network calls based on each selected tabs.

Comment: show your error log.

Comment: @gaurav Check trending_fragment.xml is it contains RecyclerView with id news_recycle ?

Comment: @DivySoni thanks for helping

Comment: @gauravtiwari your problem solved?

Comment: @DivySoni yes its solved and you mention the error correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create one Fragment add three times in setUpViewPager method.

2.) And set argument to that Fragment object with some screen differentiate number.

3.) In that Fragment, get that screen number from getArguments method.

4.) Now based on that number, call your apis in single Fragment.

You don't need to create three different fragments to just display data in RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
I hope this helps you.

```
Context mContext = rootView.getContext();

LinearLayoutManager  mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager)
```

And you want to get current Tab Title, 
then, using this ,you can get current current Tab Title:

```
adapter.getPageTitle(viewpager.getCurrentItem());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment may call `onDestroyView()` method before coming response from server, In this case it will give `NullPointerException` if you do any work on UI elements(Views), so always check for it:

```
@Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                if(getActivity==null){
                return;
                }
                //do your UI code here
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                if(getActivity==null){
                return;
                }
                //do your UI code here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set OnPageChangeListener to view pager and in onPageSelected method you will get currently selected fragment(pager position) then you can call particular api call according to which fragment is selected.

eg.

viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

```
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
     //  here you will get currently selected fragment
     //  selected fragment - adapter.getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

This line indicates that the recyclerview which are you trying to load doesnnot have a layoutmanager attached.

Replace

```
rv.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(news, R.layout.news_list_item, getContext()))
```

by

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(news, R.layout.news_list_item, getContext()));
```

in the Fragment1 class